# MySQL query takes over 15 minutes, doesn't seem like its THAT much data

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design, relational-database

So, here is my query:

```
SELECT content FROM buttons WHERE qid_id in
  (SELECT distinct qid_id FROM groups_qids WHERE group_id IN
    (SELECT 5 
     UNION
     SELECT id FROM groups WHERE parent_id=5
     UNION
     SELECT id FROM groups WHERE parent_id IN 
       (SELECT id FROM groups WHERE parent_id=5)))
  button_type_id=8;
```

Basically, there is a table called groups, and I want to find all groups who within 2 levels point to group_id=5 as its parent.  These groups are associated with a qids table, through groups_qids, so I want to find all qids associated with all those groups I just found.

THEN, we have buttons which point to a qid, so I want to find all buttons whose qid points to a qid amongst that list, computed above.

What's surprising is that the subquery:

```
select distinct qid_id from groups_qids where group_id in 
    (select 5 
     union 
     select id from groups where parent_id=5 
     union 
     select id from groups where parent_id 
       in (select id from groups where parent_id=5));
```

-- will run in 0.37 sec, returning 10547 rows.

The buttons table has 99770 rows in it.

Also, here is the output of the EXPLAIN:

```
mysql> explain select content from buttons where qid_id in (select distinct qid_id from groups_qids where group_id in (select 5 union select id from groups where parent_id=5 union select id from groups where parent_id in (select id from groups where parent_id=5))) and button_type_id=8;
+----+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type            | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                            |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | buttons      | ALL             | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 91710 | Using where                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | groups_qids  | ALL             | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 11133 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | NULL         | NULL            | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  NULL | No tables used               |
|  4 | DEPENDENT UNION    | groups       | eq_ref          | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | func |     1 | Using where                  |
|  5 | DEPENDENT UNION    | groups       | eq_ref          | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | func |     1 | Using where                  |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | groups       | unique_subquery | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | func |     1 | Using where                  |
| NULL | UNION RESULT       | <union3,4,5> | ALL             | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  NULL |                              |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I use a subquery that returns 211 rows (instead of 10547), the query still gets stuck.

```
mysql> show full processlist;
| 634878 | root | localhost | qid  | Query   |  104 | Sending data | select content from buttons where qid_id in (select distinct qid_id from groups_qids where group_id in (select 10 union select id from groups where parent_id=10)) |
```

More curiosities...
For this query:
    select content from buttons where qid_id in (select distinct qid_id from groups_qids where group_id = 10);
It also takes forever.  And, the funny part is...that sub-query, has 0 results, and MySQL can compute this in 0.00 sec.

content is a TEXT type on buttons, which, I'm guessing is a big part of the problem here...  (Though in this last query, you'd still think it'd return immediately.)  That's the only part of the table definition that stands out to me, but here is the full thing:

```
mysql> desc buttons;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| key                | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| qid_id             | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| button_type_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content            | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sort               | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| img                | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| img_ext            | varchar(6)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent             | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| enabled            | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| share_gate         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted            | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| qr_id              | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| function_type      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| function_folder_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: The problem is that if you use nested subqueries like you do, you can't  predict the actual computational cost of the operation. My wild guess is that your nested subquery in 'SELECT id FROM groups WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM groups WHERE parent_id=5)))' is slowing everything down. Plus you are running SELECT id FROM groups WHERE parent_id=5 two times, which is not optimal. I would suggest that you break down your query, run the nested ones individually and store them in variables, UNION them. Apart from that, you could take a look at the EXISTS operator, which runs much faster.

Comment: Please post your all related table structure I mean create table code and also show some sample input and expected output. @Tom

Comment: you should 'join' tables instead of 'nesting' the queries.

Comment: Let me make this simple, I can do THIS query:
    select distinct qid_id from groups_qids where group_id in (select 5 union select id from groups where parent_id=5 union select id from groups where parent_id in (select id from groups where parent_id=5))
which gives me ~10k results in a fraction of a second.  That query is a list of ids.  

Then from that intermediate query, I want to do 
    select content from buttons where qid_id in @thatintermediatequeryresult;

Can I do that?  I don't think the intermediate query has any performance issues...that outer query messes it all up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Try to put index in q_id. (2) Instead of using `IN`, try to join subquery

```
SELECT content FROM buttons btns
JOIN 
    (SELECT distinct qid_id FROM groups_qids WHERE group_id IN
        (SELECT 5 
         UNION
         SELECT id FROM groups WHERE parent_id=5
         UNION
         SELECT id FROM groups WHERE parent_id IN 
           (SELECT id FROM groups WHERE parent_id=5))) tbl ON tbl.qid_id = btns.qid_id
WHERE btns.button_type_id=8;
```

Comment: Thanks...this one did it.  I was trying to get down the EXISTS sub-query style like other users mentioned but had difficulty making it work.  Since the problem for me was in the outermost query, changing that one from an IN to a JOIN worked out for me.

Comment: The `IN (SELECT ... )` construct is less efficient than other options.